# Three.js Rotate object on sphere radius

Tags: javascript, three.js, geometry

I would like to set object at the end of sphere radius based on object.position.set (x,y,z)

In typical mathematic formula for coordinates of the point on sphere we have:

```
var x = radius * Math.cos(phi) * Math.cos(theta);
var y = radius * Math.cos(phi) * Math.sin(theta);
var z = radius * Math.cos(phi);
```

I use

```
var x = radius * Math.cos(angleZ) * Math.cos(angleX);
var y = radius * Math.cos(angleZ) * Math.sin(angleX);
var z = radius * Math.cos(angleZ);
```

I know that this is wrong becasue thete and phi are not this angles
How can i connect this 3 angles angleX, angleY, angleZ to transformt it to phi and theta

In Three js i have :

```
cylinderX.rotation.x = degToRad(angleX); 
cylinderX.rotation.y = degToRad(angleY);                    
cylinderX.rotation.z = degToRad(angleZ);
```

- degToRad - function which change deg to radians

where

```
angleX is angle between y plane and z plane
angleY is angle between z plane and x plane
angleZ is angle between x plane and y plane
```

phi and theta are difrrent angles becasue theta is angle between radius and plane

I run animation and position of object ( x,y,z) and itts location on sphere plane is wrong

How can i resolved this problem ?

To be more specific , here below is my code and example:

http://newdesignlive.neomedia.info/index.html

I would like to set this green cube at the end of this red cuboid when car is rotating in all angles on all axis x,y,z

In arrays : x[...], y[...], z[...] you have values of angles how car (object) is rotating on all axis (X, Y, Z);

I do not know how to connect angleX, angleZ, angleY to "phi" and "theta" to set "green cube" on correct position x,y,z depend on radius = 100 for example;

In animate.js here is all code I add it here bellow to

```
    var container, stats, camera, scene, renderer, object;          
    var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0;

    var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
    var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

    var angleX=0, angleY=0, angleZ=0, G=0;
    var x;  var y; var z; 
    var times = [];

    x = ["0", "10", "20","30", "40", "50" ];                                
    y = ["0", "20", "40","60", "70", "80" ];    
    z = ["0", "30", "60","90", "120", "150"  ];     
    gX = ["1", "1.4", "0.7", "0.4", "1", "1.2", "0.5", "1.2", "1.4", "1.3", "1", "0.7" ];
    gY = ["1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "3", "1.2", "1.4", "1.3", "1", "2" ];
    gZ = ["1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "3", "1.2", "1.4", "1.3", "1", "2" ];   


    generateTimesForAngles();
    generateTimesForG();

    var currentTransform = 0;
    var currentStep = 0;
    var intervalTime = 20;
    var intervalTimeG = 50

    setInterval(transformAngleX,intervalTime);
    setInterval(transformAngleY,intervalTime);
    setInterval(transformAngleZ,intervalTime);
    setInterval(transformGX,intervalTimeG);
    setInterval(transformGY,intervalTimeG); 
    setInterval(transformGZ,intervalTimeG);             

    init();
    animate();          

    function setVectorDirection (position, gValue)
    {
        var gValue = document.getElementById('g').value;
        gValue = gValue*10;

        var direction = document.getElementById("VectorDirection");
        var position = direction.options[direction.selectedIndex].value;

        var darkMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x222222 } );
        var wireframeMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x222222, wireframe: true, transparent: true } );                 var multiMaterial = [ darkMaterial, wireframeMaterial ];


        var x;
        var y;              
        x = 120 + gValue - gValue/2; 
        y = 110;
    }

    function init(objectfilename, materialfilename) {

        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
        renderer.setClearColor( 0xDEDEDE, 1 );

        container = document.createElement('div');
        document.body.appendChild(container);   
        container.appendChild( renderer.domElement )                    

        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000 );
        camera.position.y = 200;
        camera.position.z = 0;
        camera.position.x = 400;


        controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera );
        controls.addEventListener( 'change', render );

        scene = new THREE.Scene();

        var gridHelper = new THREE.GridHelper( 500, 100 );      
        gridHelper.setColors(0xFFFFFF, 0xFFFFFF);               
        scene.add(gridHelper);


        var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
            color: 0x0000ff
            });

        var initColor = new THREE.Color( 0xFFFFFF );
        var initTexture = THREE.ImageUtils.generateDataTexture( 1, 1, initColor );

        var groundMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial
        ( 
            { 
            color: 0xEDEDED, 
            specular: 0xEDEDED, 
            map: initTexture }
            );

        var groundTexture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture
            ( 
                "red.jpg", 
                undefined, 
                function()
                { 
                    groundMaterial.map = groundTexture 
                } 
            );

        groundTexture.wrapS = groundTexture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
        groundTexture.repeat.set( 25, 25 );
        groundTexture.anisotropy = 16;

        var backgroundmesh = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 20000, 20000 ), groundMaterial );
        backgroundmesh.position.y = -200;
        backgroundmesh.rotation.x = - Math.PI / 2;
        backgroundmesh.receiveShadow = true;
        scene.add( backgroundmesh );

        setVectorDirection();

        light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);

        light.position.set(0, 100, 60);
        light.castShadow = true;
        light.shadowCameraLeft = -60;
        light.shadowCameraTop = -60;
        light.shadowCameraRight = 60;
        light.shadowCameraBottom = 60;
        light.shadowCameraNear = 1;
        light.shadowCameraFar = 10000;
        light.shadowBias = -.0001
        light.shadowMapWidth = light.shadowMapHeight = 1024;
        light.shadowDarkness = .7;
            scene.add(light);


        mesh1 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
        mesh1.position.set(100,100,100);
        scene.add( mesh1 );


        var geometry;

        loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();

        var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
        map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('gtare.jpg'),   
        colorAmbient: [0.480000026226044, 0.480000026226044, 0.480000026226044],
        colorDiffuse: [0.480000026226044, 0.480000026226044, 0.480000026226044],
        colorSpecular: [0.8999999761581421, 0.8999999761581421, 0.8999999761581421]
            });

        mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
        scene.add( mesh );


        grotX = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.CylinderGeometry( 0.4, 8, 8, 40, 1 ),new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x458B00 } ));

        cylinderX = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry(10,10,10)/*THREE.CylinderGeometry(4, 4, 300, 50, 50, false)*/,new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x458B00 } )); 

        cylinderY = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry(10,10,10/*4, 4, 300, 50, 50, false*/),new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x01C5BB } )); 
        cylinderZ = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry(10,200,10/*4, 4, 300, 50, 50, false*/),new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xFF0000 } ));


        scene.add(cylinderX);
        scene.add(cylinderY);
        scene.add(cylinderZ);

        loader.load('car.js', function (geometry, materials) {
            var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
        map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('gtare.jpg'),   
        colorAmbient: [0.480000026226044, 0.480000026226044, 0.480000026226044],
        colorDiffuse: [0.480000026226044, 0.480000026226044, 0.480000026226044],
        colorSpecular: [0.8999999761581421, 0.8999999761581421, 0.8999999761581421]
            });

          mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );

          mesh.receiveShadow = true;
          scene.add(mesh);
          render(); 
        });



    }


    function degToRad(degrees) {
        return degrees * Math.PI / 180.0;
    }

        function radToDeg(radians) {
        return parseInt(radians * 180.0 / Math.PI);
    }

    function onWindowResize() {

        camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
        camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
        render();
    }

    function generateTimesForAngles() {
        var baseTime360 = 10000;
        for(i=0;i<z.length-1;i++) {
            var timeMiddle = 10000;
            times.push(timeMiddle);
        }
    }

    function generateTimesForG() {
        var baseTimeallG = 5000;
        for(i=0;i<g.length-1;i++) {
            var timeMiddleG = 240;
            times.push(timeMiddleG);
        }

    }

    function transformGX() {
        var steps = times[currentTransform] / intervalTime;
        var singleStepGX = (gX[currentTransform+1]-gX[currentTransform]) / steps;


        if(currentStep<steps) {
            currentStep++;
            GX = +gX[currentTransform] + (+currentStep * +singleStepGX); 

        } else if(currentTransform<times.length){
            currentStep = 0;
            currentTransform++;
            GX = gX[currentTransform];
        } else {
        }
    }

    function transformGY() {
        var steps = times[currentTransform] / intervalTime;
        var singleStepGY = (gY[currentTransform+1]-gY[currentTransform]) / steps;


        if(currentStep<steps) {
            currentStep++;
            GY = +gY[currentTransform] + (+currentStep * +singleStepGY);

        } else if(currentTransform<times.length){
            currentStep = 0;
            currentTransform++;
            GY = gY[currentTransform];
        } else {

        }
    }

    function transformGZ() {
        var steps = times[currentTransform] / intervalTime;
        var singleStepGZ = (gZ[currentTransform+1]-gZ[currentTransform]) / steps;

        if(currentStep<steps) {
            currentStep++;
            GZ = +gZ[currentTransform] + (+currentStep * +singleStepGZ); // Pamiętaj o plusach!!!
        } else if(currentTransform<times.length){
            currentStep = 0;
            currentTransform++;
            GZ = gZ[currentTransform];
        } else {
        }
    }

    function transformAngleX() {
        var steps = times[currentTransform] / intervalTime;
        var singleStepAngle = (x[currentTransform+1]-x[currentTransform]) / steps;

        if(currentStep<steps) {
            currentStep++;
            angleX = +x[currentTransform] + (+currentStep * +singleStepAngle); 

        } else if(currentTransform<times.length){
            currentStep = 0;
            currentTransform++;
            angleX = x[currentTransform];
        } else {

        }
    }

    function transformAngleY() {
        var steps = times[currentTransform] / intervalTime;
        var singleStepAngle = (y[currentTransform+1]-y[currentTransform]) / steps;

        if(currentStep<steps) {
            currentStep++;
            angleY = +y[currentTransform] + (+currentStep * +singleStepAngle); 
        } else if(currentTransform<times.length){
            currentStep = 0;
            currentTransform++;
            angleY = y[currentTransform];
        } else {

        }
    }

    function transformAngleZ() {
        var steps = times[currentTransform] / intervalTime;
        var singleStepAngle = (z[currentTransform+1]-z[currentTransform]) / steps;

        if(currentStep<steps) {
            currentStep++;
            angleZ = +z[currentTransform] + (+currentStep * +singleStepAngle); // Pamiętaj o plusach!!!

        } else if(currentTransform<times.length){
            currentStep = 0;
            currentTransform++;
            angleZ = z[currentTransform];
        } else {

        }
    }

    var i = 0;

    function animate() {

        i++;
        requestAnimationFrame( animate );

        var x = 100 * Math.sin(degToRad(angleX))* Math.cos(degToRad(angleY)); 
        var y = 100 * Math.sin(degToRad(angleX))* Math.sin(degToRad(angleY));
        var z = 100 * Math.cos(degToRad(angleX));   

        z = -z;
        cylinderX.position.set(x,y,z);  
        cylinderY.position.set(0, 0, 0);
        cylinderX.rotation.x = degToRad(angleX);
        cylinderX.rotation.y = degToRad(angleY);                    
        cylinderX.rotation.z = degToRad(angleZ);
        cylinderZ.rotation.x = degToRad(angleX);
        cylinderZ.rotation.y = degToRad(angleY);                    
        cylinderZ.rotation.z = degToRad(angleZ-90);     

        mesh.rotation.x = degToRad(angleX);     
        mesh.rotation.y = degToRad(angleY);
        mesh.rotation.z = degToRad(angleZ);
        render();
    }

    //renderowanie obiektów
    function render() {

        renderer.render( scene, camera );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to add the object to a parent `Object3D`, and move the object the appropriate distance (radius of the sphere you want to match the surface of) on *one* of the `x`, `y` or `z` axis. Add the parent to the scene and position it on the centre of the sphere you want to match (the child object should now fall on the sphere where that intersects the axis you used). With that set up like this, you can rotate the parent to position your object on the sphere.

Comment: Can someone put here a example how to do his?

Comment: Three JS changed where some of their dependencies live breaking the original JS fiddle (which is fantastic by the way). I updated the fiddle to include the new resource locations ---- Just going to leave this here for anyone else that might be looking to use this solution: http://jsfiddle.net/8nxn6/2/